# converting csv to json using python pandas

Tags: python, json, csv

I need to convert a csv file into a json file. I have tried some python examples that are available on-line but none seem to fit my needs.

My csv file contains a header then multiple rows for each date. Im not entirely sure on the terminology but I think I need each unique id in the first field in the csv (NA, NE, SE) to have its own object in the json.

Any help would be appreciated. Cheers!

Example of input

```
A1,sDate,eDate,A2
NA,01/01/2023,01/05/2023,2
NE,01/01/2023,01/05/2023,3
SE,01/01/2023,01/05/2023,4
NA,02/01/2023,02/05/2023,5
NE,02/01/2023,02/05/2023,6
SE,02/01/2023,02/05/2023,7
```

My desired output would be

```
{
    "NA": [
        {
            "sDate": "01/01/2023",
            "eDate": "01/05/2023",
            "a2": 2
        },
        {
            "sDate": "02/01/2023",
            "eDate": "02/05/2023",
            "a2": 5
        }
],
    "NE": [
        {
            "sDate": "01/01/2023",
            "eDate": "01/05/2023",
            "a2": 3
        },
        {
            "sDate": "02/01/2023",
            "eDate": "02/05/2023",
            "a2": 6
        }
],
    "SE": [
        {
            "sDate": "01/01/2023",
            "eDate": "01/05/2023",
            "a2": 4
        },
        {
            "sDate": "02/01/2023",
            "eDate": "02/05/2023",
            "a2": 7
        }
]
```

I was using the pandas library to help with this but its not giving the results I need.

```
import pandas
import json

df = pandas.read_csv('file.csv', names=("A1","sDate","eDate","A2"))

df.to_json('file.json', orient='records')

with open('file.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump({'NA': df.to_dict(orient='records')}, f, indent=4)
```

```
{
    "NA": [
        {
            "A1": "NA",
            "sDate": "01/01/2023",
            "eDate": "01/05/2023",
            "A2": "2"
        },
        {
            "A1": "NE",
            "sDate": "01/01/2023",
            "eDate": "01/05/2023",
            "A2": "3"
        },
            "A1": "SE",
            "sDate": "01/01/2023",
            "eDate": "01/05/2023",
            "A2": "4"
        },
         {
            "A1": "NA",
            "sDate": "02/01/2023",
            "eDate": "02/05/2023",
            "A2": "5"
        },
        {
            "A1": "NE",
            "sDate": "02/01/2023",
            "eDate": "02/05/2023",
            "A2": "6"
        },
            "A1": "SE",
            "sDate": "02/01/2023",
            "eDate": "02/05/2023",
            "A2": "7"
        }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `defaultdict` is very useful for this kind of processing

```py
def build_structure(reader: typing.List[dict]) -> dict:
    structure = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for d in reader:
        structure[d["A1"]].append(
            {"sDate": d["sDate"], "eDate": d["eDate"], "a2": d["A2"]}
        )
    return structure
```

1. Read the file and create a `csv.DictReader` of the file and convert it to a list,
2. Send the `list` to the `build_structure` function.
3. You have a `defaultdict`, you can `dumps` it with `json`.

```py
import collections
import csv
import json
import typing


def read_csv(file_name: str) -> list:
    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        return list(reader)


def build_structure(reader: typing.List[dict]) -> dict:
    structure = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for d in reader:
        structure[d["A1"]].append(
            {"sDate": d["sDate"], "eDate": d["eDate"], "a2": d["A2"]}
        )
    return structure


data = read_csv("data.csv")
structure = build_structure(data)
print(json.dumps(structure))
# {'NA': [{'a2': '2', 'eDate': '01/05/2023', 'sDate': '01/01/2023'},
#         {'a2': '5', 'eDate': '02/05/2023', 'sDate': '02/01/2023'}],
#  'NE': [{'a2': '3', 'eDate': '01/05/2023', 'sDate': '01/01/2023'},
#         {'a2': '6', 'eDate': '02/05/2023', 'sDate': '02/01/2023'}],
#  'SE': [{'a2': '4', 'eDate': '01/05/2023', 'sDate': '01/01/2023'},
#         {'a2': '7', 'eDate': '02/05/2023', 'sDate': '02/01/2023'}]}
```

If you want a beautified json string, you can use `json.dumps(structure, sort_keys=True, indent=4)` instead:

```py
>>> print(json.dumps(structure, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
{
    "NA": [
        {
            "a2": "2",
            "eDate": "01/05/2023",
            "sDate": "01/01/2023"
        },
        {
            "a2": "5",
            "eDate": "02/05/2023",
            "sDate": "02/01/2023"
        }
    ],
    "NE": [
        {
            "a2": "3",
            "eDate": "01/05/2023",
            "sDate": "01/01/2023"
        },
        {
            "a2": "6",
            "eDate": "02/05/2023",
            "sDate": "02/01/2023"
        }
    ],
    "SE": [
        {
            "a2": "4",
            "eDate": "01/05/2023",
            "sDate": "01/01/2023"
        },
        {
            "a2": "7",
            "eDate": "02/05/2023",
            "sDate": "02/01/2023"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas and groupby:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv", keep_default_na=False)
res = {}
for a1, df_gp in df.groupby('A1'):
    res[a1] = df_gp.drop(columns='A1').to_dict(orient='records')
print(json.dumps(res, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "NA": [
        {
            "sDate": "01/01/2023",
            "eDate": "01/05/2023",
            "A2": 2
        },
        {
            "sDate": "02/01/2023",
            "eDate": "02/05/2023",
            "A2": 5
        }
    ],
    "NE": [
        {
            "sDate": "01/01/2023",
            "eDate": "01/05/2023",
            "A2": 3
        },
        {
            "sDate": "02/01/2023",
            "eDate": "02/05/2023",
            "A2": 6
        }
    ],
    "SE": [
        {
            "sDate": "01/01/2023",
            "eDate": "01/05/2023",
            "A2": 4
        },
        {
            "sDate": "02/01/2023",
            "eDate": "02/05/2023",
            "A2": 7
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Using this pandas library or some other method, how would you remove the quotes around the dates and change the column name of "A2" to something else?

Comment: You can specify `parse_dates=['sDate', 'eDate']` inside `read_csv`. However this won't be JSON serializable. To rename A2: `df = df.rename(columns={"A2": "new_name"})`